# Nginx: return 301 and 404 managed by Certbot

Tags: nginx, certbot

Because `server_name` is `www.foo.com`, when the following paragraph is passed, `$host` must be equal to `www.foo.com`, isn't it ? So, what's the interest of adding a `return 404` statement ? In which case could it be executed ?

Also, is it possible to write some log in `/var/log/nginx/access.log` when `if` is passed ?

```
server {
    if ($host = www.foo.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;

    server_name www.foo.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This section enforces (redirects) requests for **[www.foo.com](http://www.foo.com)**:

```
if ($host = www.foo.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot
```

This section returns a 404 for any hostname:

```
return 404; # managed by Certbot
```

This means if someone arrives with the HTTP Host header containing [www.foo.com](http://www.foo.com), they will be redirected to the HTTPS URI. Otherwise, a 404 (Not Found) error will be returned.

This style is typically used when:

1. You want to ensure that visitors arrive with the correct host name and not via the IP address only.
2. For multi-domain configurations. The last rule returns 404 because the site being accessed is not one of the declared hosts.

Comment: Thanks but I still didn't get it... `server_name` being `www.foo.com`, how `$host` could be different ? I'm probably misunderstanding the role of `server_name` directive.

Comment: @DevonDahon When an HTTP client connects to your server's IP address, it should set the name of the host (domain) that it wants to access. Web servers support hosting multiple hosts (domains) on the same IP address. $host is the HTTP Host value. Bots and hackers often scan the Internet using only the IP address. They will get a 404 response instead of accessing the configured host (website).